# Implementing (switch\toggle button) depending on API level

Tags: android, android-switch, android-togglebutton

My application will run on api level 9 devices or higher. Now i have a toggle_button on one of the layouts. I want to change this toggle button to switcher if the device is apilevel 14 or higher. How can i implement this? Sorry for my english.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are creating the content/pages in xml, simply copy your xml with same name but  to the `layout-v14` folder. Then change ToggleButton to SwitchButton, and Android will take care of rest :)
If you are coding it in jave, use:

```
if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH){
    //Add Switch
}else{
    //add toggle
}
```

And when you'll want to use both (when using defining in xml) with the same java code use:

```
CompoundButton bt_toggle= (CompoundButton) findViewById(R.id.some_button);
bt_toggle.setChecked(false);
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. Can you advise some interesting library for supporting switchers in api level 9?

Comment: http://ankri.de/switch-button-for-android-2-3-gingerbread/
Check this code out, for download click the .zip option above the code
for implementing it, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5514281/how-to-use-own-view-in-layout

Comment: this is for api level 10 :)

Comment: This is your decision, Android support library weights around 1MB after compilation and proGuard run.  
I dont know anything better, but im not expert

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution! [link](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/SwitchCompat.html)

It just adds a support library. And you can use switchers from api-level7!